# Excel: Looking up a value and indicating if it's being used elsewhere with INDEX/MATCH

Tags: excel, indexing, match, formula

```
=IF(B2="userID",IF(INDEX($C$2:$C$6,MATCH(A2,$A$2:$A$6,0),1)<>"","userID fixed",""),"not user ID type fix")
```

Hi all,

I've got a little issue I hope someone can shed some light on. Above, I've included by formula being used and screenshots below of outcomes and desired outcomes.

I have a situation in which column A can be defined as unique user ID's. These ID's have multiple required fixes against them, represented by each row, so in column A, there can/will be instances in which a user ID shows up multiple times.

However, when tracking these fixes, ID's are addressed by user ID. So if user ID issue is fixed, the other issue pertaining to that ID will be fixed.

To track this, column C will represent a column that will accept a value to indicate that the fix has been complete and where it is not NULL, it will indicate that the other fixes attached to this have been also completed via an index/match look up using the subject cell to indicate whether it is fixed or not.

My issue is that, using my formula, the MATCH function does not work as intended unless there is a value inputted in the first instance (row) of the relevant column, in the example below it would be C2. If a value is entered in C2, it populates as expected, but if a value is entered in C3 it does not populate as expected.

See the column "match test", it seems like the issue is that MATCH looks at the first instance of column A values (user ID) and because that row was NULL, it does not trigger my formula. However, I would like it to check each instances of the values in column A and if there is a value in any of the corresponding values in row C, fill all values in column D with the corresponding instances.

Is there a more appropriate way to go about doing this? Is match the wrong function to use? Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Outcome when the first instance of the ID is filled in the corresponding cell in column C

[image: Outcome when the first instance of the ID is filled in the corresponding cell in column C]

Outcome when instance other than the first is filled in the corresponding cell in column C

[image: Outcome when instance other than the first is filled in the corresponding cell in column C]

DESIRED Outcome when instance other than the first is filled in the corresponding cell in column C

[image: DESIRED Outcome when instance other than the first is filled in the corresponding cell in column C]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `COUNTIFS`:

```
=IF(B2="userID",IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,C:C,"x")>0,"userID fixed",""),"not user ID type fix")
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! I wasn't too familiar with the COUNTIFS function, but this solution is really elegant and provided a great example for future use cases. Thanks a million!!